# Hue HBase API Error: None

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hue

When I use The Web UI for HBase in hue，I just get an error message: API Error: None, and the log says：

```
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:30 +0000] access       INFO     114.112.124.241 admin - "GET /hbase/ HTTP/1.0"
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:31 +0000] access       INFO     114.112.124.241 admin - "POST /hbase/api/getClusters HTTP/1.0"
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:31 +0000] access       INFO     114.112.124.241 admin - "GET /debug/check_config_ajax HTTP/1.0"
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:31 +0000] access       INFO     114.112.124.241 admin - "POST /hbase/api/getTableList/HBase HTTP/1.0"
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:31 +0000] thrift_util  INFO     Thrift exception; retrying: None
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:31 +0000] thrift_util  INFO     Thrift exception; retrying: None
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:31 +0000] thrift_util  WARNING  Out of retries for thrift call: getTableNames
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:31 +0000] thrift_util  INFO     Thrift saw a transport exception: None
[30/Jun/2015 21:16:31 +0000] middleware   INFO     Processing exception: Api Error: None: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/share/hue/apps/hbase/src/hbase/views.py", line 65, in api_router
    return api_dump(HbaseApi().query(*url_params))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/share/hue/apps/hbase/src/hbase/api.py", line 48, in query
    raise PopupException(_("Api Error: %s") % e.message)
PopupException: Api Error: None
```

and config in hue.ini is

```
[hbase]
hbase_clusters=(Cluster|ip-172-31-13-29.cn-north-1.compute.internal:9290)
```

and thrift port is 9290 (hbase.regionserver.thrift.port), Enable HBase Thrift Server Framed Transport is false (hbase.regionserver.thrift.framed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Thrift Server v1 (and not v2)?

Did you make sure that 'framed' was also selected in the hue.ini?

```
[hbase]
thrift_transport=framed
```

How to setup the [HBase Browser](http://gethue.com/the-web-ui-for-hbase-hbase-browser/) and [use it with Security](http://gethue.com/hbase-browsing-with-doas-impersonation-and-kerberos/).

Comment: 1. I check hbase configuration and see “Enable HBase Thrift Server Framed Transport” property is unchecking, so I need not to select 'thrift_transport=framed' in hue.ini。And I try to select 'thrift_transport=framed' in hue.ini,it does not work with error as before

Comment: 2. I select 'hbase.regionserver.thrift.framed=false' in hbase configuration and remove 'thrift_transport=framed',it cannot work as before

Comment: I install cdh4.7.1 with cloudera manager4.7.1，how can I check the version of thrift?

Comment: the thrift version is 0.9.0,and I see 'namespace cpp  apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift' in 'thrift/Hbase.thrift'.And I see  'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift' and 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift2', so I am using Thrift Server v1

Comment: If using CM, as long as the HBase and HBase Thrift services are checked in the Hue configuration tab it should just work. Are you using Security? Any info in the Thrift or HBase logs? If the Thrift server still up?

Comment: yes,I checked the HBase and HBase Thrift services in the Hue configuration tab, I am not using Security,and no info in Thrift and HBase logs in debug,Thrift server is running now, and I can visit it's web ui in my browser

Comment: thanks Romain, when I set hbase.regionserver.thrift.compact=false,it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
HBASE VERSION 1.4.6
HUE VERSION 4.2.0
```

I am running clustered `HBASE` on `AWS EMR`

To fix the issue

1) Start thrift1 on master node of HBASE. Default port is 9090 or make sure its running

```
./bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift -p PORT_NUMBER
```

2) Change `hui.ini` or `pseudo-distributed.ini` configuration settings

```
[hbase]

  hbase_clusters=(Cluster|MASTER_IP_OR_STANDALONE_IP:9090)

  # Copy these files from where hbase is installed in case of distributed hbase. 
  # Like hbase-site.xml , hbase-policy.xml and regionalservers file
  hbase_conf_dir=PATH_OF_HBASE_CONFIG_FILES

  # 'buffered' used to be the default of the HBase Thrift Server.
  thrift_transport=buffered
```

3) Restart the hue server